# Как получить порядковый номер строки

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть такая таблица и код выборки из базы:

```
id - name
1 - Москва
4 - Самара
5 - Саратов
7 - Вологда

$q = 'Са'; // поиск для примера

$query = DB::table('city')->select('*');
$query->where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%");
$rows = $query->get();
```

Результат:

```
 id - name
 4 - Самара
 5 - Саратов
```

Как мне в переменной `$rows` узнать какой это номер строки?

Из этого примера номера строк должны быть 2 и 3.

И самое главное номера `order by` должны быть по `id`, даже если сортировка по `name`, но номер строки нужно получить именно по сортировки `id`

Также с учетом постраничной навигации

Comment: Посчитать в запросе "номера" в дополнительном поле (ROW_NUMBER()  в CTE) и в основном запросе вывести с ними.

Comment: @Akina, а как в виде кода такое записать?

Comment: Зависит от версии MySQL (если версия пятая - это грустно, придётся использовать переменные). А уж как это превратить в код laravel - я вообще фиг знает, может, даже придётся оставить raw sql.

Comment: @Akina, читал про `DB::raw` но ничего не понял, сейчас придумал немного костыльное решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Устал голову ломать, придумал такое решение на свой вопрос, главное задачу мою решает.

```
$cityRow = [];
$cityI = 1;
$rows = DB::table('city')->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();
foreach($rows as $row){
    $cityRow[$row->id] = $cityI++;
}

$q = 'Са'; // поиск для примера
$query = DB::table('city')->select('*');
$query->where('name', 'like', "%{$q}%");
$rows = $query->get();

@foreach($rows as $row)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $cityRow[$row->id] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $row->name }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте преобразовать в синтаксис laravel вот такой запрос

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, COUNT(t2.id) AS rownum
FROM city AS t1
JOIN city AS t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
WHERE t1.name LIKE '%{$q}%'
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.name
```